# silverlight gradient

Tags: silverlight

I was wondering if there is a way to programmatically change a stopgradient color specified in XAML.  For example:

```
<Rectangle Width="1280" Height="1024">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.0" />
            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.25" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

When I click a button on my screen I want to change the "black" gradientstop to "red".  Any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an x.Name attribute to the gradient stop in XAML.
Then you can access it by name in the code behind.

```
<GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.0" x:Name="MyStop" />
```

then your code would be

```
MyStop.Color=Colors.Red;
```

You should also look at doing this with the Visual State Manager and a GoToState Action on the Click - then you could do this without any code.  You shouldn't mix code with design - the design (color, gradient info) should be kept in XAML and use your code for logic.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  Here is the code in C#:

```
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
        GradientStop gs_black = new GradientStop();
        GradientStop gs_white = new GradientStop();
        LinearGradientBrush lgb = new LinearGradientBrush();

    private void cb_test_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        rect.Width = 1280;
        rect.Height = 1024;

        gs_black.Offset = 0;
        gs_black.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0);

        gs_white.Offset = .25;
        gs_white.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255);


        lgb.StartPoint = new Point(0, 0);
        lgb.EndPoint = new Point(0, 1);

        lgb.GradientStops = new GradientStopCollection();

        lgb.GradientStops.Add(gs_black);
        lgb.GradientStops.Add(gs_white);

        rect.Fill = lgb;

        canvasname.Children.Add(rect);
    }

  private void cb_change_color_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        lgb.GradientStops.Remove(gs_black);
        gs_black.Offset = 0;
        gs_black.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 255, 0);
        lgb.GradientStops.Add(gs_black);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using '<'GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.0" x:Name="MyStop" /> worked.  I searched for this topic online and a lot of people said it couldn't be done that way.

Answer (score 0):

To change the color of GradientStop used in a resource you need to use the x:Key, for example

```
(this.Resources["xKeyName"] as LinearGradientBrush).GradientStops[0].Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 69, 69, 69);
```

This will set the color for the first GradientStop in the following UserControl resource

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="xKeyName">
        <GradientStop Offset="0" /><!-- Colorset via code-behind -->
        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1.0" />
    </LinearGradientBrush>
</UserControl.Resources>
```